# i am having some trouble with my sql file it shows these error while i tried to import ,please give me the solutions

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I am having some trouble with my SQL file while I tried to import:

```
USE [db_events]

GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Tbl_UserReg]    Script Date: 04/09/2016 16:05:08 ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_UserReg](

[UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

[LogId] [int] NOT NULL,

[Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,

[Mob] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,

[Email] [varchar](100) NULL,

[CName] [varchar](100) NULL,



CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl_UserReg] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

(



[UserId] ASC

)WITH (PAD_I[...]
```

it shows these error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'U' at line 1

Comment: You're trying to use SQL-Server syntax with MySQL.

Comment: You can't import a SQL-Server dump file into MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use this code

```
  CREATE TABLE Tbl_UserReg(

    UserId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

    LogId INT NOT NULL,

    NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

    Mob VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,

    Email VARCHAR(100) NULL,

    CName VARCHAR(100) NULL
    )
```

Thank you....